# Is there a good way to use Excel CELL() formula without prior knowledge of the locale the file will be used in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, localization

The Excel [CELL() function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) takes a required parameter **info_type** and an optional parameter **reference**.

The parameter **info_type** takes a **localized** string to determine the type of information to return.

As the worksheet functions seem to be localized only in the user interface, but not in the files themselves, localization is usually not a problem. But in this case, the **string parameter**, which technically is a piece of data, not code, is localized!

Take the German localized function call

```
=ZELLE("dateiname")
```

The English equivalent would be

```
=CELL("filename")
```

But, when transferring the file from a German to an English Excel, the transparently "translated" function call correctly changes from `ZELLE()` to `CELL()`, but the parameter stays `"dateiname"`, instead of the correct `"filename"`!

Is there a way to produce a formula that will work in any and all Excel localizations? Preferrably without trying out all 35+(?) localization language parameter strings for each CELL() function call using cascaded `IFERROR`-blocks?

Initially I had hoped that the string parameters were just keys to some internal enumeration, and that knowing the actual values behind the keys and passing them instead of the supposed key sting to work. But the function actually requires exactly one of the allowed - localized - strings.

I cannot find anything useful, anywhere.

Comment: Better write to Microsoft Help Desk,, to get corrected method,, since Excel itself is available in multiple language !

Answer (score 2):

If the first argument of the Cell function is in English, then it should work in all locales.

If you want to test this on the same computer, it is not sufficient to change just the language pack, but you must also change the Windows settings for locale, and then - for good measure - even give it a reboot before opening the file using the other language and locale.

Comment: Great, just literally looking at the problem from a different angle seems to have been the solution, here. - If no better answer shows up, I'll accept your's. - Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this might work for you: [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2016/new-excel-add-in-lookup-localized-function-names/a9f1ca64-dd15-4998-8f8a-51606d66a452) I have not tried it personally but it claims to solve your issue. I would guess that the hangup will be regarding the quote marks, it may translate everything else but fail on things within quotes.

Comment: @JustinDoward You completely missed the point.

Comment: @teylyn No, I don't think so. The link may not entirely satisfy the requirement, but I do not think there is a solution to the requirement... but you may be right, in which case "good point, well made".

Comment: @JustinDoward Can you explain which part of the link you posted addresses the problem?

Comment: @teylyn did you have a look at the garage project? It is attempting to address the issue of translating functions across languages with a single click, not sure what you or me are missing but I do not see how the link does not add to this thread as it appears to contain the most comprehensive approach available to addressing the issue that was raised in the original question. Out of interest does the solution you provided work such that the string between the quotes is changed from German to English or is it accepted in German to the English function, or does it have to be modified?

Comment: Sorry @teylyn, I just realised I replied to your response rather than the original question, that was not my intent - I am still getting used to the format of this site.

Comment: Excel does not need function translation. People do. The question here was about a parameter that is a string in a specific language, and making sure that, just like Excel will automatically translate the function itself between the locales (without any translation tool), the parameter should also dynamically adjust to the locale that the file is opened in.  The function translator does not help solve that problem. At all. It is for humans who know a function in one language, and who work on a computer in an unfamiliar locale and want to find what that function is in that language.

Comment: @JustinDoward this is part 2 of my previous comment. So, while Excel handles the transition from one locale to another just fine, what happens with a string parameter? And my answer is above.

Comment: If the function translator does not address that issue it seems to be a great deal of work they have put into something that achieves almost nothing, I wonder which government they work for? Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: > I'll accept your's. - Thanks!

That answered the question perfectly: following this advice, you may use CELL() robustly without knowing target locale. Why not yet accepted? :-)

Comment: @MikeKaganski Because that's how people are. I'm sure they meant to accept, but then forgot and maybe haven't come back to the site. I've had answers accepted five years after I posted them. It happens.